# What is Best Practice For UISearchBar With Buttons

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uistackview

I would like to make the following UI for my app:
[image]
Where I have a search bar where the user can search for stickers and has the option to add a new one. I've tried several approaches for this UI but none of them work very well. First I tried embedding the `UISearchBar` and `UIButton` in a `UINavigationbar` but using them as bar button items didn't let me work with auto layout. I tried a similar thing with `UIToolbar`. Then I figured `UIStackView` would be easier to lay out. And it was. In the image above I have the `UISearchBar` and the `UIButton` in the `UIStackView`. The only problem is I have a hairline below the search bar but not below the button. Any advice on how to properly do this?

UPDATE: I added some code to remove the hairline but it's leaving 1 px of black beneath it. Here's the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let color = UIColor.clear()
    searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0
    searchBar.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: does it appear on the device ?

Comment: I'm using the simulator. It appears in the Simulator. I should clarify that I know how to remove the hairline and I probably will. My question is is using a stack view in this case good practice?

Comment: All the cases you mentioned have no drawbacks. It depends on your requirement .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to spend too much time fighting with the UISearchBar, you may simply do your own searchBar, based on a simple UIView.

This way you are sure to keep control when iOS is upgraded over the years..

I personnaly think it is not necessarily the right solution to subclass or customize OS classes.